# Запуск видео через input[type="button"]

Tags: javascript, html, css, видео

Мне нужно, чтобы при клике на кнопку запускалось видео, я это сделал и все работает, но проблема в том, если на одной странице несколько видео при клик на любую кнопку запускается только первой видео

```
<div class="video_with_link">
    <video id="video" width="380px" height="250px" src="video/videoplayback.mp4" class="PlayStopVideo"></video>
    <input type="button" class="PlayStopVideo">
</div>
<div class="video_with_link">
    <video id="video" width="380px" height="250px" src="video/videoplayback.mp4" class="PlayStopVideo"></video>
    <input type="button" class="PlayStopVideo">
</div>
<script>
    var video;
        window.onload = function() {
            video = document.getElementById("video");
        }
        $(document).on('click','.PlayStopVideo',function(){
            if(video.paused) {
                video.play();
            }
            else {
                video.pause();
            }
        });
</script>
```

Я понимаю, что нельзя, чтобы на одной странице был один и тот же ID, но писать 10 функций для 10 видео как-то не хочется, хотелось бы универсальную функцию

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сделать 2 разных id для video и передавать их в виде аргумента управляющей функции. внутри функции добераться до элемента будете так.

```
function video(id){
    var video = document.getElementById(id)
    video.play();
}
```

Что бы ещё упростить можно для каждой кнопке передать data-id=" нужное id видео для кнопки" и по this в обработчике click вытаскивать его и ставить в функцию.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var video;
$(document).on('click','.PlayStopVideo',function(){
    video = document.getElementById(this.dataset.videoID);
    if(video.paused) {
        video.play();
    }
    else {
        video.pause();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video_with_link">
    <video id="video1" width="380px" height="250px" src="video/videoplayback.mp4" class="PlayStopVideo"></video>
    <input type="button" class="PlayStopVideo" data-videoID="video2">
</div>
<div class="video_with_link">
    <video id="video2" width="380px" height="250px" src="video/videoplayback.mp4" class="PlayStopVideo"></video>
    <input type="button" class="PlayStopVideo" data-videoID="video2">
</div>
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку Cannot read property 'paused' of null